# Android JobIntentService ADB Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE

Tags: android, adb, jobintentservice

I'm trying to setup a JobIntentService and test it using adb.

When I use this command:

```
adb shell am startservice -a "com.example.package.action.DO_THING"
```

It produces the error:

```
Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following entry:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.intents.IntentHandlerService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.example.package.action.DO_THING"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: My guess is that `adb shell am` lacks that permission.

Comment: JobServices seem to require this permission. Are JobIntentServices not intended to handle external broadcasted intents?

Comment: "Are JobIntentServices not intended to handle external broadcasted intents?" -- correct. They are purely for internal use within the app. If you need to trigger a job from outside, you will need to use something else (explicit broadcast `Intent` to a manifest-registered receiver, for example).

Comment: If you reply with the above as an answer I'll mark it as such so you get credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JobIntentService`, like `JobService`, is only usable from within an app. You cannot have another app talk to those services, nor is there any sort of direct `PendingIntent` option.

(in theory, you might be able to talk to a `JobIntentService` from other apps on Android 4.4 and older, as I'm not certain how `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"` will be handled when that permission is undefined, but I wouldn't count on it)

For IPC, you will need to use something else. So, for example, if you want a `PendingIntent` to be processed by a `JobIntentService`, create a broadcast `PendingIntent` with an explicit `Intent` pointing to a manifest-registered receiver, and have it post the job to the `JobIntentService`.