# Android BIND_JOB_SERVICE & sepolicy

Tags: android, selinux

I have a valid manifest file with the right permission & "exported" set as well. But, I still get the below error:

```
Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE
```

The command (initiated over adb) is a running a service (via "am startservice") & the manifest file has these details:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Logcat doesn't have anything useful, just throws the permission required error (which the APK already has). This seems like a sepolicy restriction since if I remove the policy (by running "setenforce 0"), then the command works fine (no errors seen as well)

I've tried running in "permissive" mode but it doesn't show any useful messages. Is there any way to figure out what policy needs to be turned on?

Here's the actual error from logcat:

```
05-16 14:03:32.892   566   897 W ActivityManager: Permission Denial: Accessing service com.abc.def/.MyService from pid=6757, uid=2000 requires android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE
```

Comment: There isn't much to go on here. What is the command?

Comment: Sorry, the command is a running a service (via "am startservice") & the manifest file has this:  `<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />` There is nothing in logcat except the requires permission error

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your original question with the new information so it's easier to parse for others. Is the `am startservice` being initiated from within your app or via adb?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original post. I am having so much trouble creating a new-line in my response. I tried hitting 2 spaces and Enter, but once I hit Enter, it just posts my response. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: The permissions does not go in the service tag, but it is not needed to start a service via adb either way. Could you share the full error from the logs? There might be other items that are helpful.

Comment: Really? I've searched everywhere including here, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService and the permission has always been listed under the service tag. Unfortunately, I can't post the full log, but updated the original question with the related error, sorry about that

Comment: I stand corrected. This is a specific type of permission for JobIntentServices. It looks like you cannot start this via adb: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310305/android-jobintentservice-adb-error-requires-permission-android-permission-bind

Comment: Actually, I've tried running it directly from the Android shell on the target and that fails too. So, I guess that implies we can't run it from the command line (adb or not). Thanks for the link, appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was, putting the same command in a bash script and sourcing it works fine!!